# Evaluating a math function with two arguments in Python

Tags: python

Can someone explain how the correct answer here is 4?
The var a here should be "2" according to the logic of the function I see as "a=inc(a,a)" should evaluate to undefined as you have replaced the value of a in this statement?
What am I missing?

```
def inc(a,b=1):
    return(a+b)
a=inc(1)
a=inc(a,a)
print(a)
```

Comment: Are you asking why 2+2 = 4? What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: You need to learn about variable scope.

Comment: The `a` in the function is not the same as the global variable `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding 1+1 first, then you are taking that sum or 2, and then adding it by its self again so a 4

```
def inc(a,b=1):
  return(a+b) # adds 1 to a

a=inc(1) # a is 1 + 1 or 2
a=inc(a,a)# here you are adding 2 + 2
print(a) # results to a 4
```

Comment: I see. Did not know that Python interpreter kept a running tally of value of "a". Assumed that "a=inc(a,a)" declaration replaced prev value in memory so the answer would be "2". Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the interpreter first evaluates the left hand side of the code:

```
a = inc(a, a)
```

This means that it will first calculate "inc(a, a)", which will evaluate to "4", and then, it will replace the value of "a" with the value, "4", to get:

```
a = 4
```